# For loop using ordered array formatting error

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am trying to get my 'Game' to appear at the front of each line of this code however it keeps appearing at the end and I can not work out how to fix my loops so that it creates a new line at the correct time.

```
 static void Main() {

            int[,] lottoNumbers ={
                                  { 4, 7, 19, 23, 28, 36},
                                  {14, 18, 26, 34, 38, 45},
                                  { 8, 10,11, 19, 28, 30},
                                  {15, 17, 19, 24, 43, 44},
                                  {10, 27, 29, 30, 32, 41},
                                  { 9, 13, 26, 32, 37,  43},
                                  { 1, 3, 25, 27, 35, 41},
                                  { 7, 9, 17, 26, 28, 44},
                                  {17, 18, 20, 28, 33, 38}
                              };

            int[] drawNumbers = new int[] { 44, 9, 17, 43, 26, 7, 28, 19 };

            PrintLottoNumbers(lottoNumbers);

            ExitProgram();
        }//end Main

 static void PrintLottoNumbers(int[,] lottoN)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < lottoN.GetLength(0); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < lottoN.GetLength(1); y++) {
                    if(y < 1 && x > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Game" + lottoN[x, y] + " ");
                    }else {
                        Console.Write($"{lottoN[x, y],2}" + " ");
                        //Console.Write(lottoN[x, y] + " ");
                    }

                }
            }

        }//Print Function For Lotto Numbers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < lottoNumbers.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            Console.Write("Game" + lottoNumbers[x, 0] + "\t");
            for (int y = 0; y < lottoNumbers.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{lottoNumbers[x, y],2}" + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code

```
 Console.WriteLine("Game" + lottoN[x, y] + " ");
 }else {
 Console.Write($"{lottoN[x, y],2}" + " ");
```

Here you've said write out the text game + stuff and terminate with a line, otherwise, just write additional stuff to the existing line.

eg maybe it shows

> ```
> Game 1 2 3 4 5 game 1
> 2 3 4 5
> ```

If you need game to be at the beginning of a line, send a line feed first! Im guessing probably

```
Console.Writeline();     
Console.Write("Game" + lottoN[x, y] + " ");
}else {
Console.Write($"{lottoN[x, y],2}" + " ");
```

is probably more the formatting you wanted

eg

> ```
> game 1 2 3 4 5
> game 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

Comment: Getting there! Now it has a space after the 1st number :3

Answer (score 1):

Why complicate things with an `if-else`

```
        for (int x = 0; x < lottoN.GetLength(0); x++) {
            Console.Write("\nGame ");
            for (int y = 0; y < lottoN.GetLength(1); y++) {
                Console.Write($"{lottoN[x, y],2}");
            }
         }
```

Just move the writing of the game in the first loop.

This prints an additional blank line but to avoid that you can add an extra condition.

```
Console.Write((x!=0 ? "\n" : string.Empty) + "Game ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and most readable way is to extract the creation of the text for a row of entries into a separate method, then invoke that for each row. Something like this:

```
    static void PrintLottoNumbers(int[,] lottoN)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < lottoN.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game" + GetRowText(lottoN, x) );
        }

    }//Print Function For Lotto Numbers

    static string GetRowText(int[,] lottoN, int row)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < lottoN.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            builder.Append(" " + lottoN[row, x]);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```